# How fast can I run in a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vacuum, biology

One factor that limits my top running speed is air resistance. Another, much smaller, factor is the drag caused by the partial vacuum I create in my wake. Suppose instead of running on the surface of the Earth, I was running in a complete vacuum under constant gravity. Then the two mentioned factors would no longer apply. What then prevents me from gradually accelerating to arbitrary speeds? What would change if I could replace  parts of my anatomy by stronger materials (think robot legs)?

Comment: breathing vacuum is not recommended. astronauts suit is heavy, hard to pick up speed. Limit would be rate of calories burning by the muscles

Comment: Who says that those two factors are actually different?

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Comment: @Daron, find a vacuum, run as fast as you can in it, and report your results to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running on a treadmill will get rid of both factors as well without the need of a vacuum.

When someone is running they apply a force backwards against the ground which gives the acceleration, but they also apply a forwards force against the ground when each leg lands, creating a braking force. The position of the feet in contact with the ground relative to the runner's center of mass dictate whether the force is being applied forwards or backwards. Theoretically you could minimize your braking force and maximize your accelerating force by always landing your feet as close to your center of mass as possible, but this would require an increasingly greater force in order to keep your body aloft since your force vector will be originating behind you most of the time and for shorter periods of time.

See [this video](https://youtu.be/PfHNOwmmik4) and [accompanying paper](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/220/2/247) for example force patterns of running and related info.

Answer (score 5):

Aerodynamic drag plays next to no role in top speed for running. It's mostly about muscular strength, and speed of neuromuscular reflexes. More details in the paper by Weyand *et al.* in *J Appl Physiol* **89**: 1991–1999, 2000, short title is "*[Mechanical Basis of Human Running Speed](http://jap.physiology.org/content/jap/89/5/1991.full.pdf)*".

Comment: Please provide a reference for which part of the paper supports that "Aerodynamic drag plays next to no role in top speed for running"

Answer (score 3):

The drag that is caused due to air is very less compared to the force with which you run. So you will be experiencing very less difference in vacuum considering you are provided with oxygen.

you can get mode details here http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1113/jphysiol.1971.sp009381/pdf